TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null while integration of razorpay to react-native expo
I had installed the react-native-razorpay package using
$ npm i react-native-razorpay --save
I have imported the RazorpayCheckout on the top:
import RazorpayCheckout from "react-native-razorpay";
then I have created a function named paymentRazor, which has been called to an onPress functionality of a button.
var options = {
          "description": 'Payment for XYZ',
          image: 'https://imgur.com/3g7nmJC',
          "currency": 'INR',
          "key": 'API_KEY',
          "amount": amount, 
          "name": 'PAYMENT',
          "payment receipt": customer_code,
          "order_id": orderid,
          "prefill": {
            "email": 'user@example.com',
            "contact": '9999999999',
            "name": 'John Doe',
          },
          "theme": { "color": '#F37254' },
          "notes": {
            "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office",
            "customer_code": customer_code
          },
        };
        console.log(options);
        RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(`Success: ${data}`);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(`Error: ${error} | ${error}`);
        });

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null | TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null

Have you tried the sample project? https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay/blob/63c8e5cc2417ccb4b86927bb108a3e1fc9a261ef/example/SampleApp/App.js

Do provide a minimal-reproducible-issue

i have tried the sample project same error @Alex
